# How to use preg_replace to replace links and image links

Tags: php, preg-replace, preg-match, preg-match-all, preg-replace-callback

I have text that contains links and link of an images and there can have a lot of link and mix with other words.
The text below is my example text.

```
$string = "http://www.google.com/ is best know for search engine, this is Google logo ##https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png##. And you can visit http://www.youtube.com/ to watch videos. Here YouTube's logo ##http://s.ytimg.com/yts/img/pixel-vfl3z5WfW.gif##";
```

I want to use `preg_replace` to replace them like this.

```
$string = '<a href="http://www.google.com/">http://www.google.com/</a> is best know for search engine, this is Google logo <img src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png" />. And you can visit <a href="http://www.youtube.com/">http://www.youtube.com/</a> to watch videos. Here YouTube's logo <img src="http://s.ytimg.com/yts/img/pixel-vfl3z5WfW.gif"></img>';
```

This is `preg_replace` pattern for links.

```
$string = preg_replace("/([\w]+:\/\/[\w-?&;#~=\.\/\@]+[\w\/])/i","<a target=\"_blank\" href=\"$1\">$1</a>",$string);
```

This is `preg_replace` for pictures.

```
$string = preg_replace("/\#\#([\w]+:\/\/[\w-?&;#~=\.\/\@]+[\w\/])\#\#/i","<img src=\"$1\"></img>",$string);
```

Both of them work well, but they don't separate between links and image links. Please help me thanks I've tried all day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the only reliable difference between the links are the # hash marks, I think you need to use the Positive Lookbehind to add another layer of uniqueness between the regexes.

1. The first regex looks for URLs **without** hash marks to make those anchor tags

   `/((?<!##)https?:\/\/[\w-?#&;~=\.\/\@]+[\w\/])/i`
2. Then, look for any links with hash marks and make those img tags

   `/\#\#(https?:\/\/[\w-?#&;~=\.\/\@]+[\w\/])\#\#/i`
3. I also had to replace [\w]+: at the start of each regex with something more specific because \w appears to match #, so I changed [\w]+: with https?: to match http: or https:

So the final two-piece regex looks like this

```
$string = preg_replace("/((?<!##)https?:\/\/[\w-?#&;~=\.\/\@]+[\w\/])/i","<a target=\"_blank\" href=\"$1\">$1</a>",$string);
$string = preg_replace("/\#\#(https?:\/\/[\w-?#&;~=\.\/\@]+[\w\/])\#\#/i","<img src=\"$1\"></img>",$string);
```

I ran a test on this and it appeared to work for me using your example.

Comment: For `$string = preg_replace("/((?<!##)https?:\/\/[\w-?#&;~=\.\/\@]+[\w\/])/i","<a target=\"_blank\" href=\"$1\">$1</a>",$string);` how can i ignore for ** and ##?

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is probably `preg_replace_callback` that can change the replacement string according to the match result:

```
$str = preg_replace_callback('~(##)?\b((?:f|ht)tps?://\S+)(?(1)##|(?=\s|$|\pP))~',
                       function ($m) {
                           if (isset($m[1])) return '<img src="' . $m[2] . '"/>';
                           return '<a href="' . $m[2] . '">' . $m[2] . '</a>';
                       },
                       $str);
```

**pattern details:**

The pattern uses a particular feature at the end `(?(1)...|...)` that is a conditional *(if the capture group 1 exists then try this else try that)*.

`\pP` is a shortcut for the character class `\p{Punct}` that contains all ponctuation characters. I put it in the alternation to deal with this kind of string: `blah blah (http://domain.com/file.html)`

Since the pattern to describe the URL is very basic (IMO, it's a lost of time to try to make a more complicated pattern to describe an URL), to ensure that the URL is correct, you can check it with `filter_var` inside the callback function.